# getting `exceeded PCRE's line length limit` when greping (very) long lines

Tags: bash, grep, regular-expression

I have a sample file below called `reads.fq.gz`, which looks like so:

```
@read1 bla bla sample_id=PD170815
ACTGCGACCCAAACCTTGCACATTGGAC
+
%*&3&&&$$&%$%&3
@read2 bla bla sample_id=PD170815
ACTTTGACCCCAAATCGTGGAC
+
&3&&&%#%^%$%$#%$@#$@#
@read3 bla bla sample_id=PD170815
ATTTGACCCAAATGACCCAGT
+
$%^&()^$#@..;:":
@read4 bla bla sample_id=PD170815
TTGGAACGTGACGATGACCAGT
$%^&*&*^$$$#$#$#$
```

From this file I want to grep the characters that are between `@read` and the plus sign `+`

I have another `.txt` file where I specify which reads I want to grep from `reads.fq.gz`. For example, If I want to grep the information from `read1` and `read4` I would have a `list.txt` file that looks like so:

```
read1
read4
```

If I do:

```
while read p; do zcat reads.fq.gz | grep -Pzo "\@$p(.)*\n[A-Za-z]*\n\+\n"; done < list.txt
```

I get what I want:

```
@read1 bla bla sample_id=PD170815
ACTGCGACCCAAACCTTGCACATTGGAC
+
@read4 bla bla sample_id=PD170815
TTGGAACGTGACGATGACCAGT
+
```

Though this is a sample file. The file from which I want to grep is huge (23Gb) and the lines between `@read` and the plus sign `+` can be very long. So when I run the same command on my original file I get

```
grep: exceeded PCRE's line length limit
```

For each entry in `list.txt`.

Is there a way to specify something like 'no line length limit' for `grep` so that I can grep these very long lines?

Comment: I'd avoid multiline matching altogether and use something stateful like `awk -vp="$p" '$0 ~ "^@"p {b=1} b{print} /^\+/{b=0}'`

Comment: in fact, if you use awk you can avoid the shell loop as well I think: `zcat reads.fq.gz | awk 'NR==FNR {a["@"$0]; next} $1 in a {b=1} b {print} /^\+/ {b=0}' list.txt - `

Comment: Excellent, it does the job, thanks very much